# IE wrong paragraph using CSS float layout

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I am learning XHTML and CSS and I got into trouble. On my learning page I am using CSS float layout. I have floted:left side menu, and to properly render text into content section I have set its margin to be exact same size as left menu. My problem is, that text in paragraph is wrongly shifted from the place where side munu ends. This happens only in IE 8, Its OK in Chrome. Please help. [This is the site....](http://gamewrs.wz.cz/TNPW)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either increase the padding-left of your content, or increase the margin-left. Either of will make it work better in IE.

The reason this happens is IE6 and IE7 do a poor job in defining widths of block level elements. Sometimes they're 20px off.

Comment: Strange you still have it then. Another way is giving the #content a width of 670 (width:670px;). Seeing page is 800-120 = 680 that gives you 10 px to play.

Comment: Thanks I'll try when I get home, its not good to do this on the mobile phone.... :)

Comment: Well, I tried it on my friends notebook, and i doesent work. I am getting really deprssed with it.....

Comment: Hi, I just made menu 120px, and content 660px. Now its alligned OK. But I would want to know why is happenning this. Giving it just margin of 140px would not help... I though float layouts are preffered....

Comment: float layouts are great, but with older browsers there are always quirks :\